# How to set sim card contact's contact picture in galaxy ace duos

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, 2.3.3-gingerbread

Am saving one contact to the sim card in Samsung galaxy ace duos. when am trying to set a contact picture from the gallery for that contact even though am getting message like contact icon have been set still contact picture is not present. They are not in any social media's. This works fine for the phone memory contact.

Comment: I don't think you can add a picture to a SIM contact, there is certainly no space on a SIM to store a picture and AFAIK android doesn't synch SIMs with a picture unless you move them to the Phone Storage / Google

Comment: i know sim won't have the space for saving our stuffs. but phone has right phones know our sim card is placed. and one more thing is this happening for all phones?

Comment: It happens for me on a HTC One M8, an S4, an S5 and a Nexus 5. I just have them all on Google so I never lose them, and can add as many details as I want. There **might** be contacts apps on the play store that allow this, but I don't know any off hand.

Comment: i heard for moto g and s3 also it is happening. but not this phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ross suggested in his initial comment on the question itself: contact photos for SIM card contacts are not supported; so if you store that contact on SIM only, it will not be possible to link an image to it.

You could however have a copy of that contact stored either with your Google contacts or the "local" ones (which do not get synchronized). Some [contact apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer) support "linking" contacts (kind of "merge" them for display), and have the picture attached to that – though this doesn't make much sense.

I'm not sure for what reason you want to have that one contact stored on your SIM. But if it's for "backup purposes", you'd better use one of the other contact storages (Google, Local), where it can have a picture and all, and use the feature of "copy contact to SIM" for a backup – while not *displaying* SIM contacts to avoid "duplicate entries" showing up. The SIM-copy then of course will not have all the details, as SIM storage doesn't support them all.

Comment: is this for all phones am having a doubt because some of my friends telling they are adding up the sim contact picture in their phones?

Comment: I don't know of any such work-arounds. As Ross wrote, there's no space for that on the SIM card itself. It might be possible to create "links", but I'm not aware of any API doing that – so if someone has such a solution, it's most likely app specific (and not global).